# cannot dereference memnbers of typedefed struct pointer

Tags: c++, struct, pointer-to-member

I have struct definition in a file called `CFLite.c` as below

```
typedef struct CFLString    CFLString;
struct CFLString
{
    CFLObject       base;
    char *          data;
    size_t          size;
};
```

This struct have a typedef-ed pointer in `CFLite.h`

```
typedef struct CFLString *      CFLStringRef;
```

This is again #define-ed in `CFCompat.h` as

```
#include "CFLite.h"
#define CFStringRef                 CFLStringRef
```

Now, in a local function, i have a simple printing statement, which includes the header `CFCompat.h` where i'd try to print the string pointed by member variable `data`.

```
MyClass::PrintFunc(){
    CFLStringRef inVal;
    printf("--- str = %s ",inVal->data)     //<--- Compiler error here : 
`data` cannot be unresolved.

}
```

Comment: Why do you have the first typedef in the first place?

Comment: @juanchopanza Forward declaration

Comment: @nmxprime And what's wrong with just `struct CFLString;`? This isn't C, you don't need such typedefs.

Comment: @Angew, actually the base definitiion is in `c[CFLite.c]`, and the local function i'm printing is cpp file

Comment: So...the struct definition is not known in the translation unit where you attempt to use it?

Comment: @nmxprime No need for it in the code you are showing. And you don't need the typedef for a forward declaratin anyway, unless there is something else with the same name.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I'm new to cpp realm, I'm from assembly and c. So forward declaration is not needed in cpp ?

Comment: @Wintermute, it is should be known because the header is indirectly included by `CFCompat.h`

Comment: @nmxprime But you said the struct was defined in `CFLite.c`, not `CFCompat.h`.

Comment: @Wintermute, There are other class functions that do some book keeping in the same structure. Then how do they all compile without error ?

Comment: If they're not in `CFLite.c`, and unless `CFLite.c` is `#included` somewhere (which would be very odd), you have a second definition of the struct somewhere that is known to the code that uses it. Without the struct definition and just a forward declaration, pretty much all you should be able to do with the struct is to pass pointers and references to it around.

Comment: @Wintermute, let me walk around for any other definitions, or #includes of c files

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, the definition of `struct CFLString` is located in the source file `CFLite.c` and nowhere else. Which means that everywhere outside that file, the type `struct CFLString` is incomplete and thus its members are unknown.

If you want to access the members of a structure, its definition must be available (usually in a header).

Comment: But the same header in included by `CFCompat.h`

Comment: @nmxprime But the struct definition is **not** in the header. It's in the .c file!

Answer (score 1):

To dereference `inVal` - which is what the expression `inVal->data` does, the compiler needs visibility of the complete struct definition.

A forward declaration is not enough.

That means the `struct` definition needs to be in one of the header files, and that header file needs to be `#include`d (directly or indirectly) in all source files that attempt to access members of the `struct`.

Comment: The header file is included indirectly by `CFCompat.h`

Comment: Please see the edit, the header file is actually included indirectly

Comment: As I said, and you have not taken into account even with your edit, the struct definition needs to be in the header file.   Not just in CFLite.c like you describe.   It needs to be in CFLite.h.